# php regular expression to capture number from table and load into variable

Tags: php, regex

So here is the string that im scraping a page to read (using file get contents)

```
<th>Kills (K)</th><td><strong>4,751</strong></td><td><strong>0</strong></td>
```

How can i navigate to the above section of the page contents, and then isolate the 4,751 inside the above html and load it into $kills ?

*Difficulty: the number will change and have additional numbers before the comma*

Comment: I am not good at regex, but you can enclose it in a root tag and parse it as xml using simplexml.

Comment: +1 prefer a DOM or simplexml approach less dodgy

Comment: I will give that a try, im very familiar with simplexml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it to work by removing all spaces and turning the page contents into a string

```
<?
$url = "http://combatarms.nexon.net/Community/Profile.aspx?user=tect0n";
$raw = file_get_contents($url);
$newlines = array("\t","\n","\r","\x20\x20","\0","\x0B");
$content = str_replace($newlines, "", html_entity_decode($raw));
preg_match_all('|<th>.*?</th><td><strong>(\d+,\d+)</strong></td>|', $content,$match); 
?>
```

This returns

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Kills (K)4,751  [1] => Deaths (D)4,868  ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 4,751 [1] => 4,868 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
preg_match_all('|<th>.*?</th><td><strong>([\d,]+)</strong></td>|x', $subject,$match);
var_dump($match);
```

but if I were you I would use [xpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) it's is safer.

Comment: inside the th tags, can i change that to select different rows? Or will that break the whole shabang? Like there is a row for Kills, and one for Deaths

Comment: yeah the .*? would match any text ... just it would match <th>bla</th><td><strong>a number</strong></td> ... 

put like I said you probably have better to go on the xpath direction less code and less possible error

Comment: will this work if there are tabs or spaces inbetween the html tags?

Comment: nop you have to use x modifier if you wanna ignore tabs 

i.e.

preg_match_all('|<th>.*?</th><td><strong>(\d+,\d+)</strong></td>|x', $subject, $match);

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
if (preg_match("/<th>Kills \(K\)<\/th><td><strong>([\d,]+)<\/strong>/", 
               $string, $matches)) {
  $kills = str_replace(",","",$matches[1]);
} else {
  $kills = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what im using and gnarf's code returns 0

RageZ's returned an empty array

```
<?
$string = file_get_contents("http://combatarms.nexon.net/Community/Profile.aspx?user=tect0n");


if (preg_match("/<th>Kills \(K\)<\/th><td><strong>([\d,]+)<\/strong>/", 
               $string, $matches)) {
  $kills = str_replace(",","",$matches[1]);
} else {
  $kills = 0;
}
echo $kills;

?>
```

Coming up 0

Comment: ie that work 

<?php
$subject = '<th>Kills (K)</th><td><strong>4,751</strong></td><td><strong>0</strong></td>';
preg_match_all('|<th>.*?</th><td><strong>(\d+,\d+)</strong></td>|', $subject,$match);
var_dump($match);

result :

array(2) { [0]=>  array(1) { [0]=>  string(49) "Kills (K)4,751" } [1]=>  array(1) { [0]=>  string(5) "4,751" } }

Comment: Returns array(2) { [0]=>  array(0) { } [1]=>  array(0) { } }  for me

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('#\(K\).*?<strong>(.*?)</strong>#s',$html,$matches);
```

tell me that aint pretty

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('#<table class="tbl_profile">(.*?)</table>#s',file_get_contents('http://combatarms.nexon.net/Community/Profile.aspx?user=tect0n'),$m);
preg_match_all('#<tr>.*?<t.*?>(.*?)</t.*?>.*?<t.*?>(.*?)</t.*?>.*?<t.*?>(.*?)</t.*?>.*?</tr>#s',preg_replace('#(<strong>)|(</strong>)|(<!--.*?-->)#s','',$m[1]),$r);
echo 'You got '.$r[2][1].' killz';
//print_r($r);
```

now tell me thaaaaaaat aint pretty, cooooool it.